# ANT release errors

Tags: java, android, ant, apk

I'm trying to compile my app to a release build using `ant release`

I followed the procedure and generated build.xml using

`$ANDROID_HOME/tools/android update project --name MyProject -p .`

Both `$ANDROID_HOME` and `$JAVA_HOME` are exported correctly.

I saved `ant.properties`with a valid `keystore` file and `alias`

Following this, I tried to execute the command `ant clean`, which runs fine and exits with `BUILD SUCCESSFUL` message.

When I try to do an `ant release`, that's when the problem happens. I get a bunch of `javac` compile errors

```
-compile:
    [javac] Compiling 89 source files /Users/kishu27/Developer/projects/MyProject/bin/classes
    [javac] /Users/kishu27/Developer/projects/MyProject/src/com/myproject/android/fragments/SettingsDetailFragment.java:20: cyclic inheritance involving com.myproject.android.fragments.SettingsDetailFragment
    [javac] public class SettingsDetailFragment extends SettingsFragment implements OnScrollListener {
    [javac]        ^
    [javac] /Users/kishu27/Developer/projects/MyProject/src/com/myproject/android/fragments/SettingsDetailFragment.java:22: modifier private not allowed here
    [javac]     private String cat;
    [javac]                    ^
    [javac] /Users/kishu27/Developer/projects/MyProject/src/com/myproject/android/fragments/SettingsFragment.java:28: modifier private static not allowed here
    [javac]     private static final String LOG_TAG = SettingsFragment.class.getSimpleName();
    [javac]                                 ^
    [javac] /Users/kishu27/Developer/projects/MyProject/src/com/myproject/android/fragments/SettingsFragment.java:29: modifier public static not allowed here
    [javac]     public static final String KEY_OPTIONS = LOG_TAG + ".Options";
    [javac]                                ^
    [javac] /Users/kishu27/Developer/projects/MyProject/src/com/myproject/android/fragments/SettingsFragment.java:30: modifier public static not allowed here
    [javac]     public static final String KEY_CAT = LOG_TAG + ".Cat";
    [javac]                                ^
```

Does anyone have any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: This not an ANT problem, these are java compilation errors. You need to post up the source code, in order to obtain the context of the error messages.

Comment: That's a problem. Code is under NDA. I can't share that. I tried to create another project that I can share codes of but it doesn't have this same issue.

If it helps, the source is compiling a release build from Eclipse. Running `ant debug` works fine too